# OpenCV Grey scale Conversion Error

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am trying to open a video source file in OpenCV to be processed. I am following a tutorial given here: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html#lucas-kanade

Each time I attempt to open a .avi video file to be processed I receive the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\LastProjectAI\sources\samples\python2\lines.py", line 22, in <module>
    old_gray = cv2.cvtColor(old_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
error: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3402: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4
```

I have read from other posts that such an error is thrown when the source video file is neither 3 or 4 channels. However, I am using videos provided by the OpenCV tutorial so I don't see why they do not work.

Here is the full code I am working with:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('walking.avi')

# params for ShiTomasi corner detection
feature_params = dict( maxCorners = 100,
                       qualityLevel = 0.3,
                       minDistance = 7,
                       blockSize = 7 )

# Parameters for lucas kanade optical flow
lk_params = dict( winSize  = (15,15),
                  maxLevel = 2,
                  criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))

# Create some random colors
color = np.random.randint(0,255,(100,3))

# Take first frame and find corners in it
ret, old_frame = cap.read()
old_gray = cv2.cvtColor(old_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
p0 = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(old_gray, mask = None, **feature_params)

# Create a mask image for drawing purposes
mask = np.zeros_like(old_frame)

while(1):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # calculate optical flow
    p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)

    # Select good points
    good_new = p1[st==1]
    good_old = p0[st==1]

    # draw the tracks
    for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new,good_old)):
        a,b = new.ravel()
        c,d = old.ravel()
        mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
        frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
    img = cv2.add(frame,mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

    # Now update the previous frame and previous points
    old_gray = frame_gray.copy()
    p0 = good_new.reshape(-1,1,2)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

The following should be noted:

- I am using the Python editor IDLE with windows 8.
- The video file which I am trying to load is in the same directly as the Python file.

I have tried multiple video files with no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions to go about fixing this error?

EDIT:

I am able to show the frame directly after it is read from teh video capture object. However, if I try to load the frame after the for loop which draws the track, I get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.5+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prac.py", line 55, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame2', frame)
cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.5+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
```

Comment: which opencv version you are using?
In opencv 2.x cv2.line() and cv2.circle() returns empty so just remove the "mask =" and "frame=" from your code

Answer (score 1):

I think that the program is not able to find your video files. Whenever you try to load a video or image file, don't forget to make a `if condition` to check whether the video/image has been loaded or not.

`if frame data is nothing` -->> `print "frame is empty"`

else to be sure that a frame from the video has been loaded successfully, you can try to show the frame immediately once it loaded but don't forget to put a `waitKey(0)` after the `imshow statement`

First of all check if the video frames are loaded or not and let us know about it.

Comment: I employed your suggestions and have localized the error (thank you for the tips). It seems the frame variable is being populated with the correct data and can be shown directly after the video capture is read. However, if I try to show the frame after the for loop which draws the track it gives me an error (see post edit).

Comment: ok good !!! Can you just mark exactly which line is throwing an error? It might be possible that your `frame` is not declared in that scope